# WCF & ASP.NET concurrency problems

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a REST service running on ASP.NET 3.5 and I have multiple concurrent asynchronous calls from the client hitting the WCF service. They all get serialized (sequential) instead of parallel calls. Here are my settings

`InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession`

`ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`

web.config - throttling values

`<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="64" maxConcurrentInstances="64" maxConcurrentSessions="64"/>`

There are no session writes in the code.

What am I missing to make my WCF concurrent?

Comment: I guess using async calls doesn't force concurrency on your client, but rather ensures that you don't wait for responses. Have you tried `Tasks.Parrallel`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: Show us your client side code: how are you managing your proxy and how are you calling the service? By the way, be very careful when mixing PerSession and ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, this requires you'll have to manually synch access to session instance state using locks and whatnot.

Comment: The client code is through Sencha Touch code. The proxies are managed by sencha. For testing purposes I have PerCall and ConcurrencyMode.Single to guarantee different threads for each call.

Comment: I'm not sure how the proxies will be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Assume that it happens, cause PerSession mode. Try to invoke service from different clients I think that you will have parallel calls then.

With a per-session service, Max Instances is both the total number of concurrently active instances and the number of concurrent sessions.

You can use per-call type of a service than,the number of instances is actually the same as the number of concurrent calls. Or you can use asynchronous methods on the client such a *'Begin...()'*.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I was using plain old .aspx pages. No matter how many calls I made, IIS was only handling them in serial rather than parallel.

It turns out the problem was the current page gets a lock on the session, so only one page could access the session at a time, hence in serial.

I have no idea if your problem is caused by the same issue, but I figure it might be a good place to start.